# CSV attribute table to polyline shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, csv, polyline-creation, points-to-line

I have a .csv file that is an exported attribute table that I would like to reconstruct as a polyline shapefile (for reasons beyond my control I cannot access the original shapefile from which the .csv attribute table was exported, nor do I have access to metadata). To reconstruct the polylines, I must:

1. Import the .csv file,
2. Display the point data, then
3. Connect the points in the correct order to make lines.

I am able to complete  steps 1) and 2), but am having trouble with step 3).

Here is what the exported .csv attribute table looks like (hiding a few irrelevant columns):
[image]

It seems like each row represents a line and that the field "the_geom" contains the lat/long of the points that make up the line. I've tried unsuccessfully to use the xy to line and points to line tools to reconstruct.

How can I reconstruct these lines?

Comment: Actually, your conversion process is: 1) Read the ASCII fields 2) Write the resulting row.  That's it.  The geometry is stored in Well-Known Text, from which it is trivial to generate `Geometry` objects. The most important part is to ***not*** do your step two, because that could wreck the geometry. To repeat, this is not a points-to-line task, this is a line to line task. Research how to convert WKT to geometry and you'll be done.

Comment: You can easily do this in `Python` if you want, but I assume you are not looking for that?

Comment: Thank you @Vince for you advice, I researched WKT to geometry and was able to solve the problem. [Here](https://community.esri.com/thread/216142-exporting-wkt-string-from-csv-to-shapefile) is a simple script I modified to convert.

Answer (score -1):

Convert WKT to geometry using a script such as this (slightly modified code borrowed from [this](https://community.esri.com/thread/216142-exporting-wkt-string-from-csv-to-shapefile) esri community question):

```
# convert wkt to geometry and compile shapes into a single feature class
import arcpy

File = "C:\\Users\\Team\\Documents\\WKTtest\\WKT.csv"

# dimension the WKT string field and poly ID field
# the field holding the WKT string
field1 = "WKT"
# the field holding the unique ID...
field2 = "Our_ref"

# set up the empty list...
featureList = []

# set the spatial reference to a known EPSG code
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(27700)
# iterate on table row...
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(File)
row = cursor.next()
while row:
    print (row.getValue(field2))
   
    WKT = row.getValue(field1)
    # this is the part that converts the WKT string to geometry using the defined spatial reference
    temp = arcpy.FromWKT(WKT, sr)
    # append the current geometry to the list
    featureList.append(temp)

    row = cursor.next()
   
# copy all geometries in the list to a feature class
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureList, "C:\\Users\\Team\\Documents\\WKTtest\\WKTShapes.shp")
```

Comment: Link-only answers tend to fail over time. A full answer would include a complete procedure within the answer body, with a link for reference.